# StimulSoft Beginning

Tags: c#, sql, stimulsoft

I have a C# project and designed stimulsoft report from his designer and now I want to connect stimulsoft report to the C# programing and export pdf.

Here are the issues:

1. I can't attach report to project
2. How can I fill dataset to declare that data I want to use in my report? (the report is something like registration paper form) (something like I want to use select SQL statement to declare my selected data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StiReport rep = new StiReport();
rep.Load("D:/YouReport.mrt");
rep.Show();
```

Comment: How can i send new data to report.  I used ur code but it work like prerendered page and didnt work with new data always use same old data.